# How to change an ion-item backgroundColor?

Tags: ionic2, background-color, angular2-template

I want to change the background color to green if the variable 'correct' is set as true or to red if it is set to false. I've tried without success:

```
<ion-item [style.backgroundcolor]="correct ? 'green' : 'red'">Hello world</ion-item>
```

Is there anyway I could do it?

Answer (score 1):

your html code.

```
<ion-item [ngClass]="correct ? 'green' : 'red'">Hello world</ion-item>
```

your css code

```
.green{
  ion-item.item.item-block.item-md.item-label-floating.item-input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
   background:green;
  }
}

.red {
  ion-item.item.item-block.item-md.item-label-floating.item-input.ng-pristine.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
    background:red;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you